# How to find $\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x^2}\int_{x}^{\infty}t^2e^{-t^2} \sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right) dt $?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Find: $\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x^2}\int_{x}^{\infty}t^2e^{-t^2} \sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right) dt$

---

My attempt:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x^2}\int_{x}^{\infty}t^2e^{-t^2} \sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right) dt =\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{e^{x^2}}}\int_{x}^{\infty}t^2e^{-t^2} \sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right) dt$$

We know: $\frac{1}{e^{x^2}}\xrightarrow[x\to \infty]{} 0$ so I thought maybe using L'Hôpital. It that is the case, I don't know how to deal with the numerator.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @SineoftheTime Thanks :)

Comment: If you know $\lim_{t\to\infty} t\sin(1/t)=1$, then you don't need to use L'Hopital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the use of the substitution $u = 1/t$, we reach
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x^{2}}\int_{x}^{\infty}t^{2}e^{-t^{2}}\sin{\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)} \ dt = \lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x^{2}}\int_{0}^{1/x}\frac{1}{u^{4}}e^{-1/u^{2}}\sin{(u)} \ du$$
Using the approximation $\sin{x} \approx x$, the limit can be rewritten as
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x^{2}}\int_{0}^{1/x}\frac{1}{u^{3}}e^{-1/u^{2}} \ du = \lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x^{2}}\left[\frac{e^{-1/u^{2}}}{2}\right]_{0}^{1/x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x^{2}}\cdot \frac{e^{-x^{2}}}{2} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Rewriting the limmand

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_x^\infty t^2 e^{x^2-t^2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)dt$$

the substitution $\tau = e^{x^2-t^2}$ becomes the obvious choice to get rid of the $x$ dependency in the integration bounds and to make the bounds finite

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1t(\tau)\sin\left(\frac{1}{t(\tau)}\right)d\tau$$

We have $t(\tau) = \sqrt{x^2-\log \tau}$, and

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{t(\tau)} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-\log \tau}} = 0$$

therefore the limit is

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1d\tau = \boxed{\frac{1}{2}}$$

using $\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\sin u}{u} = 1$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like this method. It will be straight forward. In fact, by MVT for integrals, there is $c\in(x,\infty)$ such that
$$\int_{x}^{\infty}t^2e^{-t^2} \sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)dt=c\sin\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)\int_{x}^{\infty}te^{-t^2} dt=\frac c2\sin\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)e^{-x^2}$$
and hence
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x^2}\int_{x}^{\infty}t^2e^{-t^2} \sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right) dt=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac c2\sin\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)=\lim_{c\to \infty}\frac c2\sin\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)=\frac12.$$